Discord js use Header in Embed
I want to use Headers in an embed. Like how you can make the font bigger when using a # in chat.
just using # in an embed does not work
i have seen this on an public discord
The text is not an Image.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Where in the embed are you trying to add a header? If I remember correctly, the description field does not support markdown but fields do.

Not from my testing you can't

@TheProgrammerEthan I just tried it by adding markdown in the embed and it shows like this. I got it backwards, the description field does support markdown formatting but the fields don't (despite supporting links).

@moonstar-x ok yeah it workes now, thank you.
